# Pattern Matching with Types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, types, pattern-matching

Say I have a type that contains coordinates of various objects defined as:

```
   type Point = (Int, Int)

   data Object = A Point
               | B Point
               | C Point
```

I want to create a function that would check for overlap of objects, like so

```
   checkOverlap:: Object -> Point -> Bool
```

I want to define just one function that would work for all objects, without having to specify "checkOverlap (A point) (x,y)", "checkOverlap (B point) (x,y)" and so on.

I've googled the problem but the only solution I was able to find is to add an intermediate type that would gather all of the different objects so that you can pattern match on that type. However since this is a homework exercise, I'm not allowed to modify large chunks of code to accommodate this new type.

Is there any other way? Maybe not even with pattern matching. It just seems like bad programming having to copy the same function multiple times.

Comment: You want to use typeclasses; then associate to each object a list of "points"; then define instances of this typeclass for each object, and then your `checkOverlap` function can use a type constraint, like: `checkOverlap :: (HasPoints ob) => obj -> Point -> Bool`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use record syntax if you're allowed to change the definition of `Object`:

```
type Point = (Int, Int)

data Object = A { getPoint :: Point, ... }
            | B { getPoint :: Point, ... }
            | C { getPoint :: Point, ... }

checkOverlap :: Object -> Point -> Bool
checkOverlap obj pt = doSomething (getPoint obj) pt
```

If you're not allowed to change the definition and the extraction of points is a common task, you could simply add `getPoint` as an addtional function. You can use `case` for this if you don't want to write `getPoint` several times:

```
getPoint :: Object -> Point
getPoint obj = case obj of 
                 A pt -> pt
                 B pt -> pt
                 C pt -> pt
```

If you don't want an additional function, but still want only one version of `checkOverlap`, you can move the `case` into `checkOverlap`:

```
checkOverlap :: Object -> Point -> Bool
checkOverlap obj pt = let opt = case obj of {A a -> a; B b -> b; C c -> c} 
                      in -- use opt and pt
```

Comment: I think that `getPoint`, defined with pattern matching, is the best and most natural solution given the criteria (I tend to stay away from records with a sum type).

Answer (score 1):

Consider changing your object type definition:

```
data ObjTy = A | B | C

data Object = Obj ObjTy Point

checkOverlap:: Object -> Point -> Bool
checkOverlap (Obj _ (x,y)) (u,v) = ...
```

Comment: Probably not allowed: _"However since this is a homework exercise, I'm not allowed to modify large chunks of code to accommodate this new type."_

Answer (score 1):

As in my comment, here's a way with typeclasses:

```
type Point = (Int, Int)
data Obj = A Point | B Point | C Point


class HasPoint p where
    point :: p -> Point


instance HasPoint (Obj) where
    point (A p) = p
    point (B p) = p
    point (C p) = p


checkOverlap :: (HasPoint ob) => ob -> Point -> Bool
checkOverlap ob otherPoint =
    undefined
      where
          myPoint = point ob

somethingA = checkOverlap (A (1,1)) (1,1)
somethingB = checkOverlap (B (1,1)) (1,1)
```

Comment: The typeclass here is completely pointless, you are only defining it for Obj, so why not just do `point :: Obj -> Point`?